# Breaking Change in .net 4.5 Callcontext when doing a HTTP Post to an ashx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've just installed .Net 4.5 and noticed that an existing web application, that is still running under .Net 4, is failing when I'm trying to retrieve an item from the CallContext, when before the install was working perfectly and has done for the last year.

On the AuthenticateRequest event of the application, we use the Identity of the user to load more security information about the user. This is then added to the CallContext for later use.

e.g.

```
 protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { 
             // set someValue 
            CallContext.SetData(ContextIdentifier, someValue);
        }
    }
```

The value in the callcontext is retrieved at later points in the lifecycle. e.g 
    CallContext.GetData(ContextIdentifier)

However, when requesting an .ashx from a http "POST" request, the value is now null but on a "GET" request the value is correct.

I can't find an documented reason why this has suddenly changed or whether this is now by design and why it would affect existing .Net 4 applications?

My obvious fix is to also put the data on the HTTPContext, yet without understanding the reason why I'm unsure if using the CallContext will cause issues elsewhere!

Any help / understanding would be gratefully recieved

Comment: Update: It would appear that mscorlib.dll has been updated but still doesn't explain why

Comment: It would appear this only occurs for me in IE and I get a different stack Trace.
When it works I get and additional PiplineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?572-CallContext-vs-ThreadStatic-vs-HttpContext

It appears that it was the http pipeline disposing of the call context but I must be only seeing it now because of improvements

Comment: If you need to flow state within the context of a single request, the only supported way of doing this is via the HttpContext.Items dictionary.  The other context objects (like CallContext) aren't necessarily propagated when ASP.NET performs a thread hop.

If I had to guess why this only reproed in IE, it might have something to do with Session.  If IE had a Session cookie and other browsers didn't, then the [asynchronous] SessionStateModule may have been the module that forced the thread hop.