# What would cause NHibernate's Save method to fail silently?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I've been tasked with taking over an existing ASP.NET MVC 2.0 web application that was developed by a third party developer who is no longer around to provide any assistance. There has been a requirement to add some functionality to the project, which required a project upgrade to .NET 4.5, which has been performed.

The sites underlying MSSQL 2008 R2 database access has been implemented using NHibernate version 2.0.1.4000, along with Castle and FluentNHibernate.

This is the first project I've been involved in that has used NHibernate, and I've hit a problem that has me stumped. The problem did not exist until the upgrade to .NET 4.5.

All database operations are working normally, except for one. Saving a particular object (
`Opportunity` type) to the database (this object directly maps to an Opportunity database table) fails. Prior to saving (in this case a SQL UPDATE statement), the object has new values set. But the record in the database always has the old values after saving.

Hooking up log4net to view the debug code, shows that the record is indeed updated, but using the old values in the UPDATE statement.

Surprisingly, the `Opportunity` object is intially saved using the same Save method (albeit via a different action method), and that is saving to the database just fine.

So my question is, what would cause this to happen? Being that I'm not an NHibernate expert, is it the case that the NHibernate version is simply incompatible with .NET 4.5? Or can anyone provide a pointer as to what the problem might be? I'm happy to show any code, but as there is so much I would need to know what. Below is a starter:

The Global.asax has the following references to NHibernate:

```
private static void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.BeginTransaction();
}

private static void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CommitTransaction();
}
```

The `NHibernateSessionManager` class is defined as (`Opportunity` derives from `DomainBase`):

```
public sealed class NHibernateSessionManager
{
    private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Configuration config;

    #region Thread-safe, lazy Singleton

    public static NHibernateSessionManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.nHibernateSessionManager;
        }
    }

    private NHibernateSessionManager()
    {
        InitSessionFactory();
    }

    private class Nested
    {
        internal static readonly NHibernateSessionManager nHibernateSessionManager = new NHibernateSessionManager();
    }

    #endregion


    private void InitSessionFactory()
    {
        var autoMappings = AutoPersistenceModel.MapEntitiesFromAssemblyOf<DomainBase>()
            .Where(type =>
                   typeof(DomainBase).IsAssignableFrom(type) &&
                   type.IsClass &&
                   !type.IsAbstract)
            .WithSetup(s =>
                           {
                               s.IsBaseType = type =>
                                              type == typeof (DomainBase);
                           })
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<OpportunityMappingOverride>()
            .ConventionDiscovery.Add(DefaultLazy.AlwaysTrue())
            .ConventionDiscovery.Add<CascadeAllHasOneConvention>()
            .ConventionDiscovery.Add<CascadeAllHasManyConvention>()
            .ConventionDiscovery.Add<CascadeAllReferenceConvention>();

        sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                        .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Default"))
                        .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                        .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().UseMininmalPuts().ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>())
                        .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(autoMappings))
            .ExposeConfiguration(SetConfiguration)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private void SetConfiguration(Configuration cfg)
    {
        config = cfg;
    }

    public void RegisterInterceptor(IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        ISession session = threadSession;

        if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
        {
            throw new CacheException("You cannot register an interceptor once a Session has already been opened");
        }

        GetSession(interceptor);
    }

    public void GenerateSchema()
    {
        new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false, false);
    }

    public ISession GetSession()
    {
        return GetSession(null);
    }

    private ISession GetSession(IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        ISession session = threadSession;

        if (session == null)
        {
            if (interceptor != null)
            {
                session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(interceptor);
            }
            else
            {
                session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            }

            threadSession = session;
        }

        return session;
    }

    public void CloseSession()
    {
        ISession session = threadSession;
        threadSession = null;

        if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
        {
            session.Close();
        }
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        ITransaction transaction = threadTransaction;

        if (transaction == null)
        {
            transaction = GetSession().BeginTransaction();
            threadTransaction = transaction;
        }
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        ITransaction transaction = threadTransaction;

        try
        {
            if (transaction != null && !transaction.WasCommitted && !transaction.WasRolledBack)
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                threadTransaction = null;
            }
        }
        catch (HibernateException)
        {
            RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        ITransaction transaction = threadTransaction;

        try
        {
            threadTransaction = null;

            if (transaction != null && !transaction.WasCommitted && !transaction.WasRolledBack)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseSession();
        }
    }

    private static ITransaction threadTransaction
    {
        get
        {
            return (ITransaction)CallContext.GetData("THREAD_TRANSACTION");
        }
        set
        {
            CallContext.SetData("THREAD_TRANSACTION", value);
        }
    }

    private static ISession threadSession
    {
        get
        {
            return (ISession)CallContext.GetData("THREAD_SESSION");
        }
        set
        {
            CallContext.SetData("THREAD_SESSION", value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping I won't get shot down for this question being too general. I've spent a day trying to work out what is happening, including extensive searches online.

Comment: Have you used SQL server profiler to see what's going across the wire to the database? Also, are you *sure* the database is being committed?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWhitaker. Unfortunately the client's server only has SQL Express installed, so I can't test using Profiler. I have just copied the webroot folder from the client's server (Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit) to my dev PC (Windows 7 Pro 64 bit). The only change I made was to SQL Server connection string to point to my dev database. My dev instance is saving without any problems. On the server I have verified the database role membership is set to db_owner for the user account in the connection string, and also just run an UPDATE command in a Management Studio query

Comment: I turned on debug level logging via log4net to see more verbose info, then the record updated! Turned off logging, then it went back to not working again. Could the request be completing before NHibernate completes the udpate?

Comment: Try to use an HttpModule because the EndRequest of Global is not always reliable.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWhitaker and Orlando. Apologies for misinforming you, it turns out the update statements were only being created sometimes. And the record was also being updated by ajax calls on other pages. This is not a nice site to be taking over...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that the `NHibernateSessionManager` class was storing its `ITransaction` and `ISession` objects in `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext`.

Swapping it out to store the objects in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection resolved the issue.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003988/breaking-change-in-net-4-5-callcontext-when-doing-a-http-post-to-an-ashx) which implies .NET 4.5 handles `CallContext` slightly differently compared with previous versions, which obviously caused my issue.

Because the `NHibernateSessionManager` class was in a class library that was also used by a couple of rarely used console applications, I left a fallback to the `CallContext` object as per below (not pretty, and there might have been an better alternative, but worked for me [subject to testing], as I've spent far to long figuring this one out using remote debugging):

```
    private static ITransaction threadTransaction
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return (ITransaction)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["THREAD_TRANSACTION"];
            }
            catch
            {
                return (ITransaction)CallContext.GetData("THREAD_TRANSACTION");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["THREAD_TRANSACTION"] = value;
            }
            catch
            {
                CallContext.SetData("THREAD_TRANSACTION", value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static ISession threadSession
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return (ISession)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["THREAD_SESSION"];
            }
            catch
            {
                return (ISession)CallContext.GetData("THREAD_SESSION");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["THREAD_SESSION"] = value;
            }
            catch
            {
                CallContext.SetData("THREAD_SESSION", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver! Thanks!